# How to send logs from a python application to Datadog using ddtrace?

Tags: python, logging, datadog

Let's say that I have a python routine that runs periodically using `cron`. Now, let's say that I want to send logs from it to Datadog. I thought that the simples way to do it would be via Datadog's agent, e.g. using `ddtrace`...

```py
import ddtrace

ddtrace.patch_all()

import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.warning("Dummy log")
```

...but this is not working. I've tried with both `DD_LOGS_INJECTION=true` and `DD_LOGS_ENABLED=true` but looking at the [docs](https://docs.datadoghq.com/logs/log_collection/python/#configure-the-datadog-agent) it seems that I have to configure something so the Agent will tail the log files. However, by looking at `type: file` I'd guess that I could send logs without having to worry with creating those configuration files.

What would you say is the simplest way to send logs do Datadog and how to do that from a python application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that `DD_LOGS_ENABLED` has no effect. I had to directly edit the configuration file to `logs_enabled: true`.

Answer (score -1):

You need to set your API key and app key:

```
datadog.initialize(
    api_key='YOUR_API_KEY',
    app_key='YOUR_APP_KEY',
    logs_enabled=True)
```